# Connect to mysql server in a docker container from another docker container

Tags: python, mysql, docker

### In a nutshell

Using Dockers Desktop Community Version 2.0.0.3 (31259) in macOS Mojave I have two containers:

- [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine)
- [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

From the Alpine docker I am not be able to access the mysql server instance that is running on MySQL docker.

### In details

On Alpine I am running python2 and python package mysqlclient. This is the configuration file that I use in my python application to access the mysql databases:

```
dbtype MySQLdb
connect-args {"user":"abe","db":"abe","passwd":"123"}
upgrade
host docker-mysql
port 32779
```

When I launch python application I see that it is unable to connect to mysqld server, in fact I get following error log:

```
python -m Abe.abe --config abe-my.conf
Reconnecting after rollback error: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
Reconnecting to database.
Reconnecting after rollback error: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
Reconnecting to database.
Reconnecting after rollback error: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
Reconnecting to database.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/bitcoin-abe/Abe/abe.py", line 2123, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/bitcoin-abe/Abe/abe.py", line 2117, in main
    store = make_store(args)
  File "/bitcoin-abe/Abe/abe.py", line 156, in make_store
    store = DataStore.new(args)
  File "Abe/DataStore.py", line 3427, in new
    return DataStore(args)
  File "Abe/DataStore.py", line 191, in __init__
    store.initialize()
  File "Abe/DataStore.py", line 637, in initialize
    store.configure()
  File "Abe/DataStore.py", line 944, in configure
    config = store._sql.configure()
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 643, in configure
    sql.configure_ddl_implicit_commit()
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 734, in configure_ddl_implicit_commit
    if sql._test_ddl():
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 741, in _test_ddl
    sql.drop_table_if_exists("%stest_1" % sql.prefix)
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 712, in drop_table_if_exists
    sql._drop_if_exists("TABLE", obj)
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 709, in _drop_if_exists
    sql.rollback()
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 632, in rollback
    sql.reconnect()
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 305, in reconnect
    return sql.conn()
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 288, in conn
    sql._conn = sql.connect()
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 249, in connect
    conn = sql._connect(cargs)
  File "Abe/SqlAbstraction.py", line 281, in _connect
    return sql.module.connect(**cargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 164, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

How it could be "fixed"?

I saw that the access file is `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and I found it in the mysql docker, I suppose it should not be a problem to be able to connect the two dockers so that they "see each other", but at the moment I have no idea.

Comment: This article and docker-compose will help you I think https://medium.com/@shamir.stav_83310/dockerizing-a-flask-mysql-app-with-docker-compose-c4f51d20b40d

Comment: The error message suggests your database configuration isn’t being found.  There’s one other potential source of trouble that immediately comes to mind; can you add the relevant `docker run` commands and/or your `docker-compose.yml` to the question, along with your application image’s `Dockerfile`?